# Can a Scala object be visible to only those objects in the same file?

Tags: scala

Is there an access modifier [Edit: or an idiomatic workaround which achieves the same thing] which will allow a Scala name/object to be visible to all the code in the same file, but not the whole package the file is part of?

```
package org.example.foo

private object SharedStuff {
  val bar = 0
}

class Foo {
  def apply(x: Int): String = ... something involving SharedStuff.bar ...
}

class Fuz {
  def fuzz(t: String): Int = ... something else involving SharedStuff.bar ...
}
```

In its current state, the object `SharedStuff` will be visible to all code in package `foo`. I'd like it to be visible to the classes `Foo` and `Fuz` only, without making an explicit subpackage to enclose this file.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but this smells bad. I would recommend a design that doesn't involve a singleton, and the same dependency gets injected into `Foo` and `Fuzz`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no such modifier.